# How to replace an XML attribute using XSLT when a certain other attribute is filled?

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I got two possible XML files:

```
<orders>
   <order id="1">
      <code value="001-AAA"/>
      <altCode value="002-BBB"/>
   </order>
</orders>
```

And:

```
<orders>
   <order id="2">
      <code value="001-AAA"/>
      <altCode value=""/>
   </order>
</orders>
```

I would like the `<code>`tag's `value` attribute to be replaced by the `<altCode>`tag's `value` attribute, unless the second value is empty. In that case I would like the XML te remain unchanged. The `<altCode>`tag doesn't need to be changed.

So the resulting two XML files should look like this:

```
<orders>
   <order id="1">
      <code value="002-BBB"/>
      <altCode value="002-BBB"/>
   </order>
</orders>
```

And:

```
<orders>
   <order id="2">
      <code value="001-AAA"/>
      <altCode value=""/>
   </order>
</orders>
```

**Note:** 
The actual files I like to convert are a lot more complex. So I prefer to copy the template and change the attribute after with a when-statement.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: "*I prefer to copy the template and change the attribute after with a when-statement.*" What template? You haven't showed as any template, and we don't know what it matches, which is crucial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="code/@value[string(../../altCode/@value)]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="../../altCode/@value"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael! That's it. I got most of it, but got stuck on the last part. Could you explain that part?

        `<xsl:template match="code/@value[string(../../altCode/@value)]">
            <xsl:copy-of select="../../altCode/@value"/>
        </xsl:template>`

I know the @-part, but '[ ]', string and '../' are unknown to me. Just started XSLT a few day ago.

Comment: @ChananIppel The 2nd template matches the `value` attribute of `code` on the condition expressed in the [predicate] part. The predicate evaluates to true when the sibling's `altCode/@value` is not an empty string. Otherwise the attribute will be copied as is by the 1st template. `../` means go up to the parent level.